# how to get column values and show them in select tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have tried this code [code link](http://pastebin.com/hJ1979Ex). But the result shows only the last value of column. I want to show all the values of column in select tag with choosing purpose. How to get proper value?

Comment: Add code as text please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid writing so much PHP code within the `option` tag. Write the database fetch code before and store it in array.

Later on, just loop through this `$array`.

```
  <?php
     $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
     $query = "SELECT id FROM done_add";
     $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
     $array=[];
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
         $array[] = $row['id'];
     }
   ?>

    <select name="selectlink">
        <?php foreach ($array as $arr) { ?>
            <option value = ""> <?php print($arr); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: excuse me, i want to use header column value from table, tried this, but it works not properly, could you help again? http://pastebin.com/Szs1t8Pb

Comment: Please post a new question and explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: `selectlink` will submit an an empty string no matter what is selected in the field.